# Work-arounds to InverseFunction not evaluating?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Inverse CDF of Marchenko Pastur fails to evaluate at seemingly random points as you can see below. Is there an easy workaround?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
eigMagnitude = InverseCDF[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[.5], y];
Table[eigMagnitude, {y, 0, .02, .01}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to define the CDF and then use "FindRoot" to get the inverse:

```
fun = CDF[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[.5]];
Clear[x];
ifun[y_] := x /. FindRoot [fun[x] - y, {x, 0.1}]
```

Note however that you will receive some warnings about singular Jacobian.

We may test this by:

```
ys = Table[ifun[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]

{0.0857864, 0.20889, 0.330379, 0.471649, 0.636918, 0.830466, 1.05817, \
1.32931, 1.66084, 2.09269, 2.91421}
```

and apply "fun" to these values to check if we get 0, 0.1, 0.2,...:

```
fun /@ ys

{5.04719*10^-13, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use exact values in the distribution

```
dist = MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1/2];
```

Use an explicit argument for `eigMagnitude` along with [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
eigMagnitude[y_] := InverseCDF[dist, y]

invCDF1 = Table[eigMagnitude[y], {y, 0, 0.02, 0.01}]

(* {0.0857864, 0.10532, 0.118374} *)

CDF[dist, #] & /@ invCDF1

(* {0, 0.01, 0.02} *)

invCDF2 = Table[eigMagnitude[y], {y, 0, 1, 0.1}]

(* {0.0857864, 0.20889, 0.330379, 0.471649, 0.636918, 0.830466, 1.05817, \
1.32931, 1.66084, 2.09269, 2.91421} *)

CDF[dist, #] & /@ invCDF2

(* {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1} *)

Plot[eigMagnitude[y], {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]